# Second to last non blank cell without Array Formula (Excel Online)

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Online sheet that has info coming in from a Microsoft Form. I need to find the highest non blank cell and the second non blank based on one criteria. The last non blank was easy with LOOKUP

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(K2:K1000="6"),G2:G1000)
```

However it is proving difficult to get the penultimate non blank cell without using Array formulas. Excel Online doesn't update Arrays automatically, you have to CSE each cell which is not too timely with my number of cells. Is there a non array way of getting the second to last non blank cell contents?

I have spent a long time searching and only found ARRAY solutions or ways of getting the penultimate cell when its a number. Unfortunately my entries are text. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can start at row 1 because row 1 are headers and so K1 cannot be 6 it could be:

```
=INDEX(G1:G1000,LARGE(INDEX((K1:K1000="6")*ROW(K1:K1000),0),2))
```

`LARGE(...,2)` points to second last cell fulfilling criterion in column `K`.

Else it must be more complex:

```
=INDEX(G2:G1000,LARGE(INDEX((K2:K1000="6")*(ROW(K2:K1000)-ROW(K1)),0),2))
```